# Bordered Blocks in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make some simple blocks with a black border in pygame. The way I've done it is to create a rectangle and then fill it twice, once with the outline color (black) and then again with the actual block color (but using rect.inflate()) to only fill a subset of the block, thereby producing a border. My issue is this: When I only make one block, this works like a charm. Making more in a row, however, results in the first block being made correctly and the additional blocks simply being all black, which I don't understand. My MWE to produce this issue is below:

```
import pygame

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, area, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.area = area
        self.pos = pos
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.area)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = self.pos)

def draw_brick(brick, outline_color, fill_color):
    # Fill with the outline color
    brick.image.fill(outline_color, brick.rect)
    # Fill with the actual block color
    brick.image.fill(fill_color, brick.rect.inflate(-10, -10))
    return brick.image

def get_brick(area, pos, outline_color, fill_color):
    # Create brick object
    b = Block(area, pos)
    # Draw the object
    b.image = draw_brick(b, outline_color, fill_color)
    return b


# Initialize
pygame.init()

# Set up screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 540))

# Colors
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]
red = [255,0,0]

# Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Make bricks
nbricks = 2
length = int(960. / nbricks)
width = 54
area = (length, width)
y = 0
bricks = []
for i in range(nbricks):
    x = i * (length + 1)
    pos = (x, y)
    bricks.append(get_brick(area, pos, black, red))

# Main loop
running = True

while running:
    # Check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # Draw to screen
    screen.fill(white)
    for b in bricks:
        screen.blit(b.image, (b.rect.x, b.rect.y))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

# Clean up
pygame.quit()
```

I've tried stepping through with pdb and checked the that the topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright, and center attributes of each block's rect (and the inflated rects) are correct. The blocks are drawn in the correct place, but the color of the second one is all black instead of being red with a black border like the first block, which confuses me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out what was wrong. In your code:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = self.pos)
```

This `self.rect` gets the image's size AND it's position that should be handled with `self.pos`.

The following code uses that to make its centre coloured.

```
def draw_brick(brick, outline_color, fill_color):
    # Fill with the outline color
    brick.image.fill(outline_color, brick.rect)
    # Fill with the actual block color
    brick.image.fill(fill_color, brick.rect.inflate(-10, -10))
    return brick.image
```

The `brick.rect` returns where it should fill the colour. `brick.rect` incorrectly puts the colour on the wrong place.

Try this instead:

```
import pygame

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, area, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.area = area
        self.pos = pos
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.area)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  # note the removed 'topleft = self.pos'

def draw_brick(brick, outline_color, fill_color):
    # Fill with the outline color
    brick.image.fill(outline_color, brick.rect)
    # Fill with the actual block color
    brick.image.fill(fill_color, brick.rect.inflate(-10, -10))
    return brick.image

def get_brick(area, pos, outline_color, fill_color):
    # Create brick object
    b = Block(area, pos)
    # Draw the object
    b.image = draw_brick(b, outline_color, fill_color)
    return b


# Initialize
pygame.init()

# Set up screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 540))

# Colors
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]
red = [255,0,0]

# Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Make bricks
nbricks = 2
length = int(960. / nbricks)
width = 54
area = (length, width)
y = 0
bricks = []
for i in range(nbricks):
    x = i * (length + 1)
    pos = (x, y)
    bricks.append(get_brick(area, pos, black, red))

# Main loop
running = True

while running:
    # Check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # Draw to screen
    screen.fill(white)
    for b in bricks:
        screen.blit(b.image, b.pos)        # note it uses b.pos instead of b.rect
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

# Clean up
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

GeeTransit already told you what was wrong with your code (basically mixing up relative and absolute coordinates), but I think your code is too complicated.

It can be simplified to this.

```
import pygame

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect, outline_color, fill_color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface(rect.size)
        self.image.fill(outline_color)
        self.image.fill(fill_color, self.image.get_rect().inflate(-10, -10))
        self.rect = rect

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 540))

# Colors
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]
red = [255,0,0]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

nbricks = 2
length = int(960. / nbricks)
height = 54

y = 0
bricks = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(nbricks):
    x = i * (length + 1)
    bricks.add(Block(pygame.Rect(x, y, length, height), black, red))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(white)
    bricks.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Now we have two functions and a bunch of variables less, the `Block` class is self-contained (it knows how to paint its `Surface` by itself), and using a `Group` (instead of a list) for drawing helps to keep the main loop clean.